# How to select default graphics device for charting?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, gpu, system-performance

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to use a specific graphics device for charting?

My laptop has two graphics devices; an on-board Intel chip and a Nvidia graphics card.  I noticed in Mathematica's System Information|Devices tab that all the Graphics entries only list the Intel device.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to use the Nvidia device for drawing graphics instead of the Intel device? I have some `ListPlot3D` charts that get clunky with `InterpolationOrder` turned on.  I'd also like to set `Opacity` but this crawls the rotation to a slide show. This should be easy for the Nivida graphics device but Mathematica does not appear to be using it.

Thanks,

Edmund

Comment: You could deactivate one of the GPUs to accomplish this. What operating system are you using? Ubuntu provides vgaswitcheroo for this purpose. There are similar tools available for windows.

Comment: Windows 8.1 - But I'm hoping there is a setting that can be set. I'm guessing that I'd have to reboot each time to disable and enable the Intel. I don't want to do that.

Comment: You shouldn't have to reboot your computer to change the active GPU. There should be a option in the NVIDIA control panel to change the prefered GPU for certain programs. Google might reveal more. I don't know if you can change this settings in Mathematica directly.

Comment: @paw Bingo.  You are correct.  Also, I found a setting to tell Windows to always use the Nvidia card for Mathematica.  So now I don't have to do the manual disable and re-enable.